# How to prevent Article images width being stretched to 100%

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, images

I am asking about this again because the solution from [joomla v3.6 article - uploaded image stretches to max](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/joomla-v3-6-article-uploaded-image-stretches-to-max) does not seem to work for me.

The issue I have is the article images keeping their size when I view the website on my smart phone device, whereas on my desktop monitor, their width stretch fully, resulting in humongous, degraded images in my articles.

Could anyone suggest a fix for me? I have spent hours on this but still cannot resolve it.

Many thanks.

[image: Image issue example]

The following are codes(only the ones that refer to img tag)have been extracted from the template.CSS file in the CSS folder from the website Joomla back-end.

```
.features-list .feature-row div:first-child.feature-img img {
  float: left;
}
.features-list .feature-row div:last-child.feature-img img {
  float: right;
}
article-intro img,
.article-content img {
  display: block;
  width: 100% \9;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.article-intro img[align=left],
.article-content img[align=left],
.article-intro .img_caption.left,
.article-content .img_caption.left,
.article-intro .pull-left.item-image,
.article-content .pull-left.item-image {
  margin: 0 30px 20px 0;
}
.article-intro img[align=right],
.article-content img[align=right],
.article-intro .img_caption.right,
.article-content .img_caption.right,
.article-intro .pull-right.item-image,
.article-content .pull-right.item-image {
  margin: 0 0 20px 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .article-content iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
  }
}
.img-intro-none,
.img-intro-left,
.img-intro-right,
.img-fulltext-none,
.img-fulltext-left,
.img-fulltext-right,
.img_caption {
  position: relative;
}
.img-intro-none,
.img-intro-left,
.img-intro-right,
.img-fulltext-none,
.img-fulltext-left,
.img-fulltext-right,
.img_caption {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.img-fulltext-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.img-fulltext-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.img-intro-none img,
.img-intro-left img,
.img-intro-right img,
.img-fulltext-none img,
.img-fulltext-left img,
.img-fulltext-right img {
  margin: 0;
}
.img_caption img {
  margin-bottom: 1px !important;
}
.img_caption p.img_caption {
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  article img[align=left],
  .img_caption.left,
  article img[align=right],
  .img_caption.right,
  .img-fulltext-left,
  .img-fulltext-right {
    float: none !important;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you won't find good answers that are specific to the template you use. All templates are different.

I visited your page and in your case you have this in your template CSS (line 3891 in http://elitemaths.com.au/templates/elitemaths/local/css/themes/elitemaths/template.css):
.article-intro img, .article-content img, .article-image-full img {
    width: 100%;
}

Change the **100%** part to **initial** and that should do it for you.